# Getting rid of the libvirt-qemu user in the login screen

Tags: kubuntu, kvm-virtualization, user-management

I've just installed `kvm` on my Kubuntu 18.04 and I got a new user listed on my login screen. Apparently, this is [an old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1667113). Some posts [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889995/libvirt-qemu-password) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-login-screen) suggested that I should create this file:

```
/var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu
```

with this content:

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

which I did. But it did not fix the issue. The user is still shown on the login screen. One more thing, before I create the file, I had this user listed in my System Settings as an ordinary user. After I created the file, the user is not listed in the User Manager anymore. So the file has done something but all the way through.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Thanks for the comment. I added some links.

Comment: Worth to mention it works in sddm as shown below (thanks DK Bose), but generally is an issue lacking the ability to hide systemd users by default, see bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/857651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide `libvirt-qemu` from the login screen:

Run `sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf`. If your `sddm.conf` has a section titled `[Users]`, add `HideUsers=libvirt-qemu` as a separate line to the section. If your `sddm.conf` is empty or doesn't have the section titled `[Users]`, add

```
[Users]
HideUsers=libvirt-qemu
```

Save `/etc/sddm.conf` and reboot.

If you want to hide more than one user, separate them with commas without any spaces.

This approach works in Kubuntu 18.04 and in Kubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.