# sddm-greeter ignores HideUsers in /etc/sddm.conf

Tags: lubuntu, sddm

I'm using lubuntu disco with displaymanager sddm

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 
/usr/bin/sddm
```

On my system are 2 users the main one and a test account.
I'll try to hide the test user in sddm.

```
cat /etc/sddm.conf 
[Autologin] #original entry
Session=Lubuntu #also original entry
[users]
RememberLastUser=true
HideUsers=testie
[Theme]
EnableAvatars=true
FacesDir=/usr/share/sddm/faces
```

when i start sddm-greeter in testmode the user is still present.

```
sddm-greeter --test-mode
[13:54:22.459] (II) GREETER: High-DPI autoscaling not Enabled
[13:54:22.491] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/Lubuntu.desktop"
[13:54:22.491] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/lxqt.desktop"
[13:54:22.491] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/openbox.desktop"
[13:54:22.494] (II) GREETER: Loading theme configuration from "qrc:/theme/theme.conf"
[13:54:22.498] (EE) GREETER: Socket error:  "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Invalid name"
[13:54:22.522] (II) GREETER: Loading qrc:/theme/Main.qml...
[13:54:22.609] (II) GREETER: Adding view for "LVDS1" QRect(0,0 1600x900)
```

Other changes are (like own avatar for main user) are showning up.

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197997/getting-rid-of-the-libvirt-qemu-user-in-the-login-screen/1198093#1198093 helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so a dud.

I wrote [users] but it has to be [Users]
from manpage

> [Users] section:
>
> HideUsers=
>                 Comma-separated list of Users that shouldn't show up in the user list.  Default value is empty.

sorry.